# Can't get my page to scroll?

Tags: html, nativescript

In my NativeScript Angular project, I can't get my page to scroll at all. I'm pretty new to NativeScript so it could be something simple but I'm just not sure.

Here's my html:

```html
<ActionBar title="Information" class="action-bar"></ActionBar>
<GridLayout class="pageBackground">
 <ScrollView orientation="vertical">
  <StackLayout class="main-container">
   <TextField style="margin-top: 3%;" class="form-control" hint=" First Name" returnKeyType="Next" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
   <TextField class="form-control" hint=" Last Name" returnKeyType="Next" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
   <TextField class="form-control" hint=" Password" secure="true" returnKeyType="Next" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
   <TextField class="form-control" hint=" Confirm Password" secure="true" returnKeyType="Next" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
   <WrapLayout orientation="horizontal" style="width: 90%; height: 7%; margin-bottom: 3%;">
    <Button text="Male" class="genderButtons" style="border-top-left-radius: 5; border-bottom-left-radius: 5;"></Button>
    <Button text="Female" class="genderButtons" style="border-top-right-radius: 5; border-bottom-right-radius: 5;"></Button>
   </WrapLayout>
            <Button [text]="schoolButtonText" style="border-radius: 5; height: 7%; background-color: white; width: 90%; color: rgb(0, 122, 255);" (tap)=selectSchool()></Button>
   <WrapLayout orientation="horizontal" style="margin-left: 5%; width: 95%; margin-top: 3%;">
    <Label text="Basketball" style="color: white; font-size: 18; font-weight: bold; margin-right: 3%; width: 75%"></Label>
    <Switch [checked]="basketballSwitch"></Switch>
   </WrapLayout>
   <WrapLayout orientation="horizontal" style="margin-left: 5%; width: 95%; margin-top: 2%">
    <Label text="Dodgeball" style="color: white; font-size: 18; font-weight: bold; margin-right: 3%; width: 75%"></Label>
    <Switch [checked]="dodgeballSwitch"></Switch>
   </WrapLayout>
   <WrapLayout orientation="horizontal" style="margin-left: 5%; width: 95%; margin-top: 2%">
    <Label text="Football" style="color: white; font-size: 18; font-weight: bold; margin-right: 3%; width: 75%"></Label>
    <Switch [checked]="footballSwitch"></Switch>
   </WrapLayout>
   <WrapLayout orientation="horizontal" style="margin-left: 5%; width: 95%; margin-top: 2%">
    <Label text="Softball" style="color: white; font-size: 18; font-weight: bold; margin-right: 3%; width: 75%"></Label>
    <Switch [checked]="softballSwitch"></Switch>
   </WrapLayout>
   <WrapLayout orientation="horizontal" style="margin-left: 5%; width: 95%; margin-top: 2%">
    <Label text="Soccer" style="color: white; font-size: 18; font-weight: bold; margin-right: 3%; width: 75%"></Label>
    <Switch [checked]="soccerSwitch"></Switch>
   </WrapLayout>
   <WrapLayout orientation="horizontal" style="margin-left: 5%; width: 95%; margin-top: 2%">
    <Label text="Volleyball" style="color: white; font-size: 18; font-weight: bold; margin-right: 3%; width: 75%"></Label>
    <Switch [checked]="volleyballSwitch"></Switch>
   </WrapLayout>
   <Button class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded-sm" style="width: 90%; height: 7%; padding: 0px; background-color: black; color: white; vertical-align: bottom;"
    text="Finish" (tap)=finishSignUp()></Button>
  </StackLayout>
 </ScrollView>
</GridLayout>
```

and here's my css:

```css
.pageBackground{
    background-image: url('https://backgroundtown.com/content/images/thumbs/0002610_classic-texture-dark-cool-gray.jpeg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.main-container{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

thanks so much!

**EDIT -** added css

Comment: the CSS overflow is not supported in NativeScript https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2354

Comment: Keep in mind that the content nested in ScrollView will be scrollable aout-fo-the-box if there is no enough space on the screen

Answer (score 0):

please prefer to share NativeScript Playground project instead of code snippets, such that everyone can run your example in one second on a real device.

Here is a link to one that looks like yours, with some modifications (tap functions removed, checked switches always true): https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=uAu1Fb&v=2 If there is more content than what your screen can actually show, then it will start to scroll, otherwise the behaviour won't change. Everything works perfectly on my side once I added content to fill more than what my screen can show. Do not hesitate to modify it and share the link if you still believe there is a problem.

You don't need css properties for that. Note that there is only a [subset of properties that is working for the moment](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#supported-css-properties).

Comment: oh, okay. so mine doesn't work because I have the height of my main-container to 100% so that everything else scales correctly. How else can I accomplish this?

Comment: Accomplishing what? Scrolling inside a view that doesn't need it?

Comment: it does need it. when I set the height of my main-container to 100%, the other items style correctly. here's my project to see what I mean: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=4E2kgA